# How do I create a dynamic Labda Expression using an outer variable?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a scenario where I have two tables 'side' and 'item'.

I'm trying to create the following query:

```
_db.SideTable.Where(s => s.Active && !_db.ItemTable.Any(i => i.SIDE_1 == s.ID));
```

But where SIDE_1 is actually dynamic (SIDE_1 through SIDE_20) where the number 1-20 comes from a variable 'sideId'.

I've tried creating doing the following:

```c#
// Access the parameter's SIDE_xxx property
ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ItemTable));
Expression property = Expression.Property(param, "SIDE_" + sideId);
// Access the outer variable's ID property
ParameterExpression var = Expression.Variable(typeof(SideTable), "s");
Expression property2 = Expression.Property(var, "ID");
// Make the ID property value int? since the SIDE_xxx property may be null and otherwise the expression will fail
var valExpr = Expression.Convert(property2, typeof(int?));
// The body of the expression is simply an equal check
Expression body = Expression.Equal(property, valExpr);
// Create the expression
var expression = Expression.Lambda<Func<Artikel, bool>>(body, param);
// Get the data
_db.SideTable.Where(s => s.Active && !_db.ItemTable.Any(expression)).ToList();
```

When I run this however I'm greeted with the following exception:

The parameter 's' was not bound in the specified LINQ to Entities query expression

I guess I'm not using the right syntax to access the outer 's' property correctly, but I have no idea how to do it otherwise.

Comment: If you have two tables you first need to join the tables..

Comment: an easy way to do it is by using System.Linq.Dynamic (from nuGet)... you create your lambda as a string and pass it to your `Where()` method. Here is the documentation for  it: https://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: I was actually hoping to avoid having to have to pull in even more 3rd party dependencies. You'd think that this should be pretty easy to do right...

Comment: Are your querying a sql database? In this case you can just form correct sql query to execute it and get the required SideTable items.

Comment: Yes I am, but this part is part of a larger set of conditions and I really don't want to create the whole thing as dynamic SQL. In addition, I know of other ways to solve this particular issue, right now I just really want to know how to do it with dynamic Expressions as I'm sure it must be possible :(

Comment: Underwater stone is that it is not always clear how your LINQ expression is translated into SQL. If it cannot understand or you use some unsupported functions in the expression, you may end up with retrieving all the data to the client and filtering it there. If you manage to create the expression that works, at least check the actual sql that is queried.

Comment: The problem here is that your lambda expression i => i.SIDE_1 == s.ID does not make sense out of context, because you don't know who **s** is. In the example you give, **s** is a captured variable that belongs to the outer lambda, but when you create the inner lambda **s** does not exist.

Comment: Ah thanks Adrian, you are right. When I create the entire thing as one big Expression (with _db being a ConstantExpression) it does work. Pain in the butt to write out though. If you type it out as an answer I can mark it as the correct answer.